# grep exec on a File Content in C

Tags: c, grep, operating-system, pipe, exec

I am trying to apply the grep on file content using excel. But, it is not working. I am stuck on it.  I don't know how to get the content of the file in the exec call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    int link[2];
    pid_t pid;
    char foo[4096];

    if (pipe(link)==-1)
        die("pipe");


    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        die("fork");

    if(pid == 0) {

         const char *input = "output1.txt";
         
         int fd = open(input, O_RDONLY);
         
         dup2(fd, 0);
            
         execl("grep", "grep" ,"com",  NULL);
         
         close(fd);             
         
         exit(1);

    } else {


    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output1.txt is shown below:

```
c1.txt
c1.txt~
commands1
commands1~
commandSample1.txt
commandSample1.txt~
commandSample2.txt
foo.txt
output1.txt
output2.txt
text.txt
text.txt~
```

Suggestions would be great.

Comment: "But, it is not working" [is generally not a sufficient description of an error](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Please describe how the actual behavior deviates from the desired behavior.

Comment: how to get the content of the file in the exec call.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean in this context? Does your program not compile? Or does it compile and run, but its behavior is not what you want? If that is the case, in what way is its behavior different from what you desire? Or are you not stating that you have a specific error, but merely stating that you haven't finished writing your code yet and that it is therefore "not working"? Please [edit] your question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for `execl` must be a full path. Or you can use `execlp` instead.

Comment: how to copy the file content in the pipe, so that the exec call can apply grep on the text in the pipe?

Comment: Isn't it simply failed to open the input file? You should definitely do some basic error checking.